# No wireless connection on 12.04 upgrade from ubuntu version 10 with Broadcom network controller

Tags: 12.04

I updated to 12.04 from ubuntu version 10 and now I can't connect by wifi.

It works in windows and worked in 10., Network controller is a Broadcom BCM4311. I tried to remove and then reinstall, but it did not work.

The pull down menu for networking doesn't list wireless as an option. If I try to update/install firmware I get a message that it already is the newest version.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following commands in your terminal.

```
    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

    sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then reboot